# Remove margin between rows of overflowing inline elements

Tags: html, css, tiles

I'm creating a tile-based game and am using block rendering to update a large list of tiles. I'm attempting to do this in the most simple manner, so I've been trying to work with HTML's default layouts. Right now I'm creating 'inline-blocks', omitting whitespace between the elements to avoid horizontal spaces in between them but when the blocks overflow and create a new line there is some vertical margining in which I do not know how to remove.

Example to make this a bit clearer:
http://jsfiddle.net/mLa93/13/

(Pretty much I just need to remove the spacing between the block rows while retaining the simple markup.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the effort of keeping your code as close as possible to how it was:

http://jsfiddle.net/mLa93/20/

- Add `line-height: 0` to `#container`.
- Add the hacks to make `display: inline-block` work in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

Use display: block and set float: left. See this fork:
http://jsfiddle.net/q5eSG/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `display: inline-block`, simply float the `div` elements.

Then, you just need to clear the floats on your `#container` element, which I do so using `overflow: hidden;`

Check out the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ymz3m/